# Making a grouped bar chart when my groups are varied sizes?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a bar chart out of some grouped data. This is dummy data, but the structure is basically the same. The data: [election results](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amandabee/edf73bc0bbe131435c952f5ed47524a6/raw/99febb9971f76e36af06f1b99913fcaa645ecb3e/election.csv) includes a bunch of candidates, organized into the districts they were running in, and the total vote count:

```
district,candidate,votes
Dist 1,Leticia Putte,3580
Dist 2,David Barron,1620
Dist 2,John Higginson,339
Dist 2,Walter Bannister,2866
[...]
```

I'd like to create a bar or column chart (either, honestly, though my end goal is horizontal) that groups the candidates by district.

Mike Bostock has an [excellent demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) but I'm having trouble translating it intelligently for my purposes. I started to tease it out at https://jsfiddle.net/97ur6cwt/6/ but my data is organized somewhat differently -- instead of rows, by group, I have a column that sets the category. And there might be just one candidate or there might be a few candidates.

Can I group items if the groups aren't the same size?

Comment: Just to check before playing with your jsfiddle: you want each cluster of bars according to the "district", and then, inside each cluster (each district), you want one bar for each candidate, is that correct? So, "district 1" would have just 1 bar, "district 2" would have 3 bars, and so on... is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I want. Just edited the question so that is more clear.

Comment: OK, I'll try later. The biggest problem here is not nesting the data (a necessary step), but creating <g> elements with different widths...

Comment: That makes sense. So it seems like something along the lines of `bar_width = (width - (num_dist * group_pad)) / (num_candidates + num_dists) - cand_pad` and then for each group...`group_width = (bar_width + cand_pad) * num_candidates`

Comment: The problem is that <g> elements don't have width and height attributes, they auto size to whatever they contain. If they had, it would be way more simple... I made a workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

My answer is similar to @GerardoFurtado but instead I use a `d3.nest` to build a domain per district.  This removes the need for hardcoding values and cleans it up a bit:

```
y0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.district; }));

var districtD = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.district; })
  .rollup(function(d){
    return d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d.map(function(c){return c.candidate}))
      .rangeRoundBands([0, y0.rangeBand()], pad);
  }).map(data);
```

`districtD` becomes a map of domains for your y-axis which you use when placing the rects:

```
  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", function(d,i) {
          return color(d.district);
      })
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(d.district) + districtD[d.district](d.candidate); })
      .attr("height", function(d){
        return districtD[d.district].rangeBand();
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d.votes);
      });
```

I'm off to a meeting but the next step is to clean up the axis and get the candidate names on there.

---

Full running code:

```js
var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amandabee/edf73bc0bbe131435c952f5ed47524a6/raw/99febb9971f76e36af06f1b99913fcaa645ecb3e/election.csv"
var m = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 110},
  w = 800 - m.left - m.right,
  h = 500 - m.top - m.bottom,
  pad = .1;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]);
y0 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], pad);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y0)
    .orient("left");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("$,.0f"));


var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w + m.right + m.left + 100)
  .attr("height", h + m.top + m.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + m.left + "," + m.top + ")");

        // This moves the SVG over by m.left(110)
        // and down by m.top (10)


  d3.csv(url, function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.votes = +d.votes;
    });
    
    y0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.district; }));
    districtD = d3.nest()
     .key(function(d) { return d.district; })
      .rollup(function(d){
       console.log(d);
        return d3.scale.ordinal()
         .domain(d.map(function(c){return c.candidate}))
          .rangeRoundBands([0, y0.rangeBand()], pad);
      })
      .map(data);    
  
    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.votes;
      })]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle");

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text");

      svg.selectAll("bar")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .style("fill", function(d,i) {
              return color(d.district);
          })
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(d.district) + districtD[d.district](d.candidate); })
          .attr("height", function(d){
           return districtD[d.district].rangeBand();
          })
          .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.votes);
            });

      svg.selectAll(".label")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
             return (d.votes);
             })
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
           .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.votes)})
           .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(d.district) +  districtD[d.district](d.candidate) + districtD[d.district].rangeBand()/2;})
        .attr("class", "axis");

  });
```

```css
    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path, .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

An alternate version which sizes the bars the same and scales the outer domain appropriately:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .label {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis {
      font: 11px sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
    var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amandabee/edf73bc0bbe131435c952f5ed47524a6/raw/99febb9971f76e36af06f1b99913fcaa645ecb3e/election.csv"
    var m = {
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 110
      },
      w = 800 - m.left - m.right,
      h = 500 - m.top - m.bottom,
      pad = .1, padPixel = 5;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]);
    var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal();

    var color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y0)
      .orient("left");

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickFormat(d3.format("$,.0f"));


    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", w + m.right + m.left + 100)
      .attr("height", h + m.top + m.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + m.left + "," + m.top + ")");

    // This moves the SVG over by m.left(110)
    // and down by m.top (10)


    d3.csv(url, function(error, data) {

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.votes = +d.votes;
      });

      var barHeight = h / data.length;

      y0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.district;
      }));
      
      var y0Range = [0];
      districtD = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.district;
        })
        .rollup(function(d) {
          var barSpace = (barHeight * d.length);
          y0Range.push(y0Range[y0Range.length - 1] + barSpace);
          return d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d.map(function(c) {
              return c.candidate
            }))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, barSpace], pad);
        })
        .map(data);
      
      y0.range(y0Range);
      
      x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.votes;
      })]);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text");

      svg.selectAll("bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return color(d.district);
        })
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y0(d.district) + districtD[d.district](d.candidate);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return districtD[d.district].rangeBand();
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return x(d.votes);
        });

      var ls = svg.selectAll(".labels")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g");
        
      ls.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
          return (d.votes);
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.votes)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y0(d.district) + districtD[d.district](d.candidate) + districtD[d.district].rangeBand() / 2;
        })
        .attr("class", "label");

      ls.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
          return (d.candidate);
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("x", -2)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y0(d.district) + districtD[d.district](d.candidate) + districtD[d.district].rangeBand() / 2;
        })
        .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("class", "label");

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your solution is way better than mine. The only thing missing is setting a fixed height for the bars.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thanks, yours is on the right track as well.  I thought about the fixed bar height but wasn't sure what the OP was after.  I think the best solution would be a single bar height and have the y0 range irregular depending on the number of bars.  If I get a few more minutes today, I'll update mine with this and with a second y-axis of candidate names.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hb13oe4v/

The main problem here is creating a scale for each group with a variable domain. Unlike Bostock's example, you don't have the same amount of bars(candidates) for each group(districts).

So, I had to do a workaround. First, I nested the data in the most trivial way:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.district; })
    .entries(data);
```

And then created the groups accordingly:

```
var district = svg.selectAll(".district")
    .data(nested)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.key) + ")"; });
```

As I couldn't create an y1 (x1 in Bostock's example) scale, I had to hardcode the height of the bars (which is inherently bad). Also, for centring the bars in each group, I created this crazy math, that puts one bar in the center, the next under, the next above, the next under and so on:

```
.attr("y", function(d, i) {
      if( i % 2 == 0){ return (y.rangeBand()/2 - 10) + (i/2 + 0.5) * 10}
      else { return (y.rangeBand()/2 - 10) - (i/2) * 10}
      })
```

Of course, all this can be avoided and coded way more elegantly if we could set a variable scale for each group.